# Troubleshooting connectivity over https

Tags: spring, tomcat, networking, ssl, spring-boot

I have been struggling with what I believe to be a networking issue and haven't made much progress. I wanted to see if someone had some ideas to a solution or possible steps that could provide me more information to arrive at a solution.

**Environment**
I have a mobile web application (angular.js) that is running on a html 5 browser (proprietary browser) on a barcode scanning gun (intermec ck71) connecting to a spring boot backend (non clustered single instance dev box). I wrote the mobile web app, but have assumed ownership of the spring boot back end (first time working with springboot). I am in a corporate office where I do not own the networks so I don't have a complete understanding of how things are laid out.

**Problem**
I cannot get a mobile web app to connect to our dev box on the office wireless with https

**Steps already taken**
We recently switched our team dev box to https now that development is finished. Before https the mobile application loaded properly but now just shows a spinning wheel on the mobile browser and then times out after about a minute.

The first step I did was to load the server running https locally and checked to see if I could get the scan gun to connect (which it did).

I then tried my desktop computer loading the mobile web app from the dev box (which also worked).

So it seems like the problem is isolated to the mobile gun on the wireless network at the office with https. I had the networking team make sure port 443 and port 8443 were open (which they saw were blocked and opened for me).

I retried connecting and still no luck. I ran a tcpdump on the server and see the following logs on the calls that fail

[image]

From this log it looks like the server (172.18.222.121) is closing the connection by sending packet 12 (FIN, ACK)

I added some logging to the tomcat instance of the server and see the following

```
[pid 22505] accept(41, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1037), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.31.12.157")}, [16]) = 46
[pid 22505] setsockopt(46, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, {onoff=0, linger=0}, 8) = 0
[pid 22505] setsockopt(46, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
```

but I still dont see anything about actively telling the conncetion to close. My next thought was that the box might have ip ranges whitelisted/blacklisted but according the the team that maintains the server there are no ip rules, firewalls, or anything that would interfere with network traffic on the box.

So I took this to the network team to show that traffic and they informed me that it is not a networking problem because the initial traffic is getting through and that the real problem is the FIN packet. I took that information to the server team who informed me that they had nothing on the box that would cause a FIN packet to be sent and that it was most probably a networking issue. I decided that it very well could be a server issue since that is what I have access to and everyone else believes there portion is functioning properly. I decided to create a new SSL cert as I am getting the untrusted message on the desktop browser when I connect. I created this new cert and then added it to the trusted root on the mobile scanner gun. I tried to connect again on the gun to no effect.

Next I reached out to the mobile gun vendor to see if there was any information available to me on the gun to troubleshoot it. After some troubleshooting with them they said they cannot reproduce on their side, and that because it works on my side except for connecting on that one network that it is probably a networking issue.

I went back to the server and added logging on the tomcat valve to see if I could see if I could get any additional information. When I look at the logs that the valve produces I get entries for any successful connection, but when I am unable to connect nothing shows up. My connector looks like this just for completeness.

Connector code:
`<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           keystoreFile="/home/devadmin/.ssh/keystore.p12"
           keystorePass="password" />`

And the valve:
`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
       pattern="%a %H %p %U %h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %{xxx}i" />`

**Conclusion**
So basically I can get the application to load everywhere except this one network which leads me to believe that it is networking related. Yet the network team says that it can't be networking related because the initial packets are being transmitted and that the problem is with the FIN packet being sent by the server. I have exhausted what I know about the environments... I am a mobile developer after all:) I still feel it is networking related, but don't have anything to show why the FIN packet is being sent.  Any ideas on things to check or what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be related to a redhat/java bug. When the scanner gun reached out to this instance of the server which had the right combinations of versions to cause a bug the server was throwing a SSL exception caused by the library that had the problem. I didn't see these exceptions because of the way the logging was configured.

Here is a link to the bug for people who might be reading this after me.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1022017

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect with your browser or with curl (for instance) then I suspect the issue is in the client. You said that you had to ignore the certificate violations in the browser so that's a smell, and then you said you "create a new SSL cert". Since it isn't really possible for mortals to create a trusted certificate, that means you installed a self signed or otherwise incomplete certificate, and I would hazard a guess that the client will not allow access over a connection with an untrusted cert (for good reasons)?

Comment: Yeah I had the same thought. What leads me to believe this isn't the issue is that I am using a self signed cert created the same way on my local instance. And the mobile scanner gun is able to load that instance of the webapp. Any additional thoughts? I really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Additionally I forgot to add that the Fin is being sent by the server not the client. If the client rejected the communication for security reasons wouldn't the FIN packet be sent by the client?